# "Access denied for user.." when using PyMySQL with python

Tags: python, pymysql

I can access my mysql connection in MySQL without any problem, however when I use PyMySQL I got the error:

`pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")`

I'm using the same credentials and password as I do for my regular MySQL connection which is working.

Here is my code:

```
import pymysql.cursors

# Connect to the database.
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='root',
                             db='skolen',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

print ("connect successful!!")

try:


    with connection.cursor() as cursor:

        # SQL
        sql = "SELECT * FROM Skolen.hut "

        # Execute query.
        cursor.execute(sql)

        print ("cursor.description: ", cursor.description)

        print()

        for row in cursor:
            print(row)

finally:
    # Close connection.
    connection.close()
```

Comment: Consider adding some of your code. This can also be an incorrect implementation of the connection.

Comment: Are you saying that you can connect using `mysql -h localhost -u root -ppassword` ?

Comment: Imgre g, I have added my code now. 
@thebjorn for example: in my php projects og java projects I can access my mysql database without any problem, using the same credentials and password.

Comment: Yes, but can you execute the mysql command from the same place that you're running the python script from?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this command: mysql -h localhost -u root -ppassword. 
I'm on a mac using terminal in which I execute my python script in.

Comment: @thebjorn I now tried running: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p and I get acess denied as well, now im very confused. Because I can still access my database without a problem when I run my php code or java? but I cant access through the terminal?

Comment: I found out since im using MAMP, I had to go in there and use it's mysql. Which is working fine from terminal, but how can I connect my PyMySQL to MAMP's mysql? is this even possible? do you know @thebjorn?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about macs, but the error message is normally caused by a missing grant (@'%').